# Writing columnated data to a .txt file. C++

Tags: c++

I am extremely new to C++. I have been asked to write a text file that contains columns of data. Specifically four columns comparing the real value of exponential(x) with my series expansion function to multiple degrees. x will range from 0 to 1 at intervals of 0.04.

for example

```
  x | exp(x) | M1 | M2 | M3 |
  0 |   1    | 1  |  1 |  1 |
0.04|   1.15 |1.01|1.09|1.12|  (values in example are not exact)
 .  |
 .
 .
```

However I'm struggling to get my data into neat columns in the text (.txt) file and I simply don't know how to format it.

ExpSeries() is my series function.

```
int main()
{
    std::ofstream demoFile;
    demoFile.open("Test3.txt");
    if (!demoFile)
        return 1;
    double i = 0;
    //demoFile << exp(2) << std::endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i = i + 0.04) {
        demoFile << exp(i);
        demoFile << ExpSeries(i, 2);
        demoFile << ExpSeries(i, 3);
        demoFile << ExpSeries(i, 4) << std::endl;
    }

    demoFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw).

Comment: Please dont edit the question after you got answers. Especially dont try to fix stuff you were actually asking for

Comment: There is also [Boost Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/format/doc/format.html), but that may be overkill for a beginner looking to achieve something quite simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the width of your output with [setw](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/iomanip.html) parameter

use the same fixed value for every column.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `std::setw` and `std::setprecision` from `<iomanip>` you can format it quite nice & easy.

```
demoFile << "  x  | exp(x) |  M1  |  M2  |  M3  |" << std::endl;
demoFile << "................................." << std::endl;

double i = 0;
for (; i < 1.0; i += 0.04){
    demoFile << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed; //set some precision for nice format
    demoFile << std::setw(4) << i << " |";
    demoFile << std::setw(7) << exp(i) << " | ";
    demoFile << std::setw(4) << ExpSeries(i, 2) << " | ";
    demoFile << std::setw(4) << ExpSeries(i, 3) << " | ";
    demoFile << std::setw(4) << ExpSeries(i, 4) << " | ";

    demoFile << '\n';
}
```

Here you can see the ouput (just some example doubles, but same settings):

```
   x  | exp(x) |  M1  |  M2  |  M3  |
 .................................
 0.00 |   0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
 0.04 |   0.08 | 0.12 | 0.16 | 0.20 |
 0.08 |   0.16 | 0.24 | 0.32 | 0.40 |
 0.12 |   0.24 | 0.36 | 0.48 | 0.60 |
 0.16 |   0.32 | 0.48 | 0.64 | 0.80 |
 0.20 |   0.40 | 0.60 | 0.80 | 1.00 |
 0.24 |   0.48 | 0.72 | 0.96 | 1.20 |
 0.28 |   0.56 | 0.84 | 1.12 | 1.40 |
 0.32 |   0.64 | 0.96 | 1.28 | 1.60 |
 0.36 |   0.72 | 1.08 | 1.44 | 1.80 |
 0.40 |   0.80 | 1.20 | 1.60 | 2.00 |
 0.44 |   0.88 | 1.32 | 1.76 | 2.20 |
 0.48 |   0.96 | 1.44 | 1.92 | 2.40 |
 0.52 |   1.04 | 1.56 | 2.08 | 2.60 |
 0.56 |   1.12 | 1.68 | 2.24 | 2.80 |
 0.60 |   1.20 | 1.80 | 2.40 | 3.00 |
 0.64 |   1.28 | 1.92 | 2.56 | 3.20 |
 0.68 |   1.36 | 2.04 | 2.72 | 3.40 |
 0.72 |   1.44 | 2.16 | 2.88 | 3.60 |
 0.76 |   1.52 | 2.28 | 3.04 | 3.80 |
 0.80 |   1.60 | 2.40 | 3.20 | 4.00 |
 0.84 |   1.68 | 2.52 | 3.36 | 4.20 |
 0.88 |   1.76 | 2.64 | 3.52 | 4.40 |
 0.92 |   1.84 | 2.76 | 3.68 | 4.60 |
 0.96 |   1.92 | 2.88 | 3.84 | 4.80 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setw to set the column width:

```
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
...
demoFile << setw(4) << exp(i);
demoFile << setw(5) << ExpSeries(i, 2);
```

You may also need to use std::fixed and std::precision to ensure the right number of decimal places.

Comment: Thanks guys, was a mixture of not knowing std::cout was doing (setw is much more self explanatory) and missing <cmath> when using the exponential function- silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

In a string, you can use

```
    /t
```

Between variables. For example

```
  "exp(x) /t M1 /t M2"
```

The /t is a tab. @stack_danny is showing the proper way.